# flot chart date object time incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jquery-plugins, flot

There are many answers for this question, none worked in my case, I was passing unix time. The time in x-axis is always wrong, then according to some example passed date object. Still same problem. Its not showing correct time according to date object. Please have a look in image, where I printed array data in console and time on x-axis is different. In object its 9:36 and x-axis as 5:00. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**Script**

```
 var data,options,chart;
     var fdata;
     var mons=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June","July","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    function loadChart(){
    timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = "tz";
        timezoneJS.timezone.defaultZoneFile = [];
        timezoneJS.timezone.init({async: false});
  var da = readTextFileNow();
  console.log(da.length);
  var t = "27-May-2016:19:00:00";
  var etot=[];var e200=[];var e400=[];var e415=[];var e500=[];var e502=[];var e503=[];var etotCount=0;var e200Count=0;var e400Count=0;var e415Count=0;var e500Count=0;var e502Count=0;var e503Count=0;
  for(var i=0;i<da.length;i++){
    var ts = moment(da[i].time,"YYYY-M-D H:mm:").utcOffset('+07:00');
    var dObj = new Date(ts);
    //alert(d);
    //var mmtMidnight = ts.clone().startOf('day');
    //var diffMinutes = ts.clone().diff(mmtMidnight, 'minutes');
    var a=parseInt(da[i].total);var b=parseInt(da[i][200]);var c=parseInt(da[i][400]);var d=parseInt(da[i][415]);var e=parseInt(da[i][500]);var f=parseInt(da[i][502]);var g=parseInt(da[i][503]);
    etotCount=etotCount+a;e200Count=e200Count+b;e400Count=e400Count+c;e415Count=e415Count+d;e500Count=e500Count+e;e502Count=e502Count+f;e503Count=e503Count+g;
    etot.push([dObj,a]);e200.push([dObj,b]);e400.push([dObj,c]);//ticks.push([ts,ts]);
    e415.push([dObj,d]);e500.push([dObj,e]);e502.push([dObj,f]);e503.push([dObj,g]);
  }
  data = [{ data:etot, label:"Total("+etotCount+")", lines:{show:true}, points:{ show: true}},{ data:e200, label:"200("+e200Count+")", lines:{show:true},color:"#46862b"},{ data:e400, label:"400("+e400Count+")", lines:{show:true}},{ data:e415, label:"415("+e415Count+")", lines:{show:true}},{ data:e500, label:"500("+e500Count+")", lines:{show:true},color:"#fa7e32"},{ data:e502, label:"502("+e502Count+")", lines:{show:true},color:"#d96e2c"},{ data:e503, label:"503("+e503Count+")", lines:{show:true},color:"#fa0000"}];
  options = {legend:{position:"se"},xaxis: {
                            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                            labelAngle: -90,
                            mode: "time", timeformat: "%H:%M",timezone: "browser"
                        },
                        yaxis: { axisLabelUseCanvas: true ,clickable: true,hoverable: true},
                        grid: { hoverable: true }};
        chart = $.plot($("#placeholder"),data,options);
console.log(etot);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem, though others would not do such a silly mistake :p, I was missing this js file.

**jquery.flot.time.js**